# Illustrator: Only show guides of current artboard

Tags: adobe-illustrator, artboard, guides

I have a document with multiple artboards that have different sizes, but all the same margin.

Now my problem is, that when I have two artboards next to each other, the guides I created for the margins will interfere with the artboard next to it.

Is there an option to hide all guides from artboards you are not currently working on?

Only solutions I have thought of so far:

- positioning the arboards diagonally, so guides do not interfere
- grouping guides per artboard and hide / unhide group

My preferred solution would of course be: as soon as I click on an object within an artboard, only the guides relevant for this artboard will show up, all others are hidden

Comment: I don't think there's a better way to do that, you might have to continue grouping guides per artboard

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My way to do it:

I use  <kbd>Shift</kbd>  +  <kbd>O</kbd>  to call the artboard tool.

Now when I drag a guide from the Ruler, it will limit the guide to the artboard.

When I finish it it will show my guide only inside that artboard.

Make sure to release the guides before duplicating that artboard to copy the guides too.

[image]

Comment: Don’t have enough reputation to comment or vote so, LoeNas, *hi-five_emoji!

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using InDesign for this purpose, as it handles multiple artboard sizes better and then each one can have its own margin and grid settings without interference between these.

Comment: ah wow ... I was completely unaware InDesign could handle different page-sizes.

But now that I think about it, it probably does make a lot of sense lol